# How to set kube-proxy settings using kubectl on AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I keep reading documentation that gives parameters for kube-proxy, but does not explain how where these parameters are supposed to be used. I create my cluster using `az aks create` with the azure-cli program, then I get credentials and use kubectl. So far everything I've done has involved yaml for services and deployments and such, but I can't figure out where all this kube-proxy stuff fits into all of this.

I've googled for days. I've opened question issues on github with AKS. I've asked on the kubernetes slack channel, but nobody has responded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `kube-proxy` on all your Kubernetes nodes runs as a Kubernetes [`DaemonSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) and its configuration is stored on a Kubernetes [`ConfigMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).  To make any changes or add/remove options you will have to edit the kube-proxy `DaemonSet` or `ConfigMap` on the `kube-system` namespace.

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system edit daemonset kube-proxy
```

or

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap kube-proxy
```

For a reference on the `kube-proxy` command line options you can refer to [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/).

Comment: OMG Thanks! I will test it soon. Do I need to do anything to make it take effect quicker? Also, do you know how to restart the kube-apiserver on an AKS cluster?

Comment: Not sure. Most of the cloud providers don't give you access to the master.  you could try `kube patch` the api server pod.

Comment: oh well. I keep getting "Insufficient memory" for pods when there is clearly sufficient memory and that was a workaround, but I'm having to delete the whole cluster and create it again. It's very frustrating trying to determine the correct resource limits when it behaves differently each time i edit the deployment

Comment: The daemonset existed and I believe it's working. The configmap did not exist though

Comment: Maybe the AKS config is unique and they don't use a ConfigMap